# How can I change android navigation bar color with service

Tags: android, service, colors, navigation, navigationbar

developers...I want to make an app that can change the color of navigation bar in android. Usually we can do this with this simple code.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_awesome_color)); }
```

But the problem is, I want to make this code work when application is not running (in the background) like this image.

[This is android's home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1foj.jpg)
I think this can be done with the help of android services. But we can not use getWindow() method in services.

So plese help me how can I do that, should i use WindowManager ?? or anything else plzz help me and provide me a code.☺☺☺

Comment: service don't have UI. If app is not running it means no window is open, so of which navigationbar are you trying to change the color when there is none open?

Answer (score -1):

A good way to go is to persist the color you choose inside your service. You could use [sharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) for this:

```
int yourColor = R.color.someColor;
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
    "com.example.your_filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("COLOR_KEY", yourColor);
editor.apply();
```

In your Activity you load the persisted color from the SharedPreference like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref =getSharedPreferences(
    "com.example.your_filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int yourColor = sharedPref.getInt("COLOR_KEY", R.color.defaultColor);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { 
    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(
        ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), yourColor)
    );
}
```